# Lubuntu 20.04 Install app speed

Tags: partitioning, lubuntu, lenovo

Hi I have 4gb Lenovo Ideapad, with a 500gb hard drive.  As far as I'm aware it should be more than enough to run Lubuntu 20.04.

I've just switched from Linux Mint and installed Lubuntu 20.04. I let Lubuntu do it's own partition. One of the reasons is that Mint was sometimes laggy, and I've had Lubuntu on older computers and found it to be quite fast.

Installing programs seems to be, quite a lot slower than Mint.

Anyway to speed this up?

Many Thanks,
Ralph

Comment: How are you installing programs? Are you using Discover or the command line?

Comment: So far, Discover, Muon seem to bring about the same time.  Also I installed a game on Playonlinux, that took wwwaaaaaayyyyyyy longer than it did when I had Linux Mint.

Comment: One possibility is the mirror you're using. Does changing it help?

Comment: Just tried as suggested, no change.  I forgot to mention that game is on a disc too.

Comment: If you're using applications that require more RAM than you have available (esp. if you're using GTK apps which will require extra libs in memory that will likely already exist in a different DE [you didn't say what you used on Mint but cinnamon for example is GTK), you may benefit from a *swap* partition (or swap file).  It's not created on a default installation on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Guiverc, are you sure you want me to start playing around with partitions again.  I only just got Lubuntu to install 5 hours ago!!!  Hahaha!  :)  Sounds like that would be easy enough.  Just an ext4 little swappie?  10gb?

Comment: Gotta hand it to you guiverc.  You know you're stuff.  Swap partition and a restart, much faster.  Thanks, and to the rest of you for your suggestions.

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 20.04 can use swap partitions yes, but I also mentioned *swap file* which means you didn't need to make any partition change (and is what I expected you to do; sorry I didn't make it clearer).  Also note this site needs a @ in front of the username for it to be recognized as such; I wasn't notified you referred to me.